# C: Sending a RPC Method name + Arguments

Tags: c, arrays, function, rpc, remote-access

I'm looking to send an RPC, in this case a char array containing the name of the function to execute and the list of arguments.

Arguments are ints.

Example:

```
Function name: plus
argument 1: 19
argument 2: 23
```

What I'm thinking to do, is to construct an array containing each of these, in order:

1. the octal value of the size of function name (in this example, 4)
2. the chars `'p', 'l', 'u', 's'`
3. the octal value of the size of first argument (in this case, 2, because '1', '9')
4. the char '1' and the char '9'
5. the octal value of the size of second argument (in this case 2, because '2', '3')
6. the char '2' and the char '3'

Then, I need to compact

I already have this function that encodes to octal value:

```
int decimalToOctal(int n) {
  int rem, i = 1, octal = 0;
  while (n != 0) {
    rem = n % 8;
    n/=8;
    octal += rem*i;
    i *= 10;
  }

  return octal;
}
```

But I have no idea how to compact the octal values and chars into one single array that I'll need to send through socket. Or may be will I need another type of array? Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Not related but for efficiency treat everything as binary data and don't send 19 but 10011 and send '+' rather than 'plus'.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to Benjy, you can get creative.  Why don't you try using bit fields or pack everything into a `char`.

```
struct packet 
{
    int num  : 3;
    int      : 1;
    int func : 4;
};
```

so here you've got your octal number, a padding bit and 4 bit to represent something.  Granted it won't be the full ASCII table.  Make your own packet.

Answer (score 0):

"how to send information through a network and keep it compatible" is not a new question.
you may think of sending some struct or array is a good think - but many compiler put extra bytes between each member to make excess time faster. 
so , you might want to send the data in some text form and naivly split it according to some keywords. what happens then , if one of the keywords is a valid argument itself? for example, you may want to split the text where the string `function:` is found. so what happens if an argument of the type `char[]` and the value `I'm a math student and function:` is sent? you're screwed.

that's why I suggest - use either JSON or XML (I'd go on JSON since it's smaller and more readable) . you have many C-JSON libraries out there. you simply define some form of JSON which both the client and server can parse and send everything like this. for example:

```
{
"function":"plus",
"arguments":[1,2]
}
```

many low level developers may hate the idea of using javascript concept in C, but actually, when you think about it - it's a very clever solution.
first of all, tomorrow your client or server can be written in different language then C, then you can't send any structs anymore. every decent language has JSON libraries. plus, JSON became one of the most popular structures for data exchange.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers mention you need to create a packet to serialize and send it over the network.

So the below example is for DGRAM sockets but would work with some changes for STREAM sockets as well

step one create your own packet. eg:

```
 typedef struct messageInfo
 {
     char clientReq[MAX_LENGTH];
     u_int32_t arg;
     u_int32_t value;
     //maybe add arglist // maybe send less data by encoding 
     /* required in case of unreliable connection for end     packet***u_int16_t end;*** */ 
 }__attribute__ ((__packed__))info;
```

step two send it over a socket pseudo code.

```
fd = socket( family, TYPE, 0 ); //TYPE = SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_DGRAM
//bind locally
//update peer sock structure to sendto or write
//create header start
uint8_t *tBuf = malloc(sizeof (info)); 
//memset to zero
info *pHeader = (info *)tBuf;
pHeader->value = htonl(19); //local value to send
pHeader->clientReq  = "plus";
pheader->arg = htonl(23);
//create header end
//send to receiver
sendto(serverSock, tBuf, sizeof(info),0
                             ,(struct sockaddr *) &peerV4,
                             sizeof(peerV4));
```

step three receive pseudo code

```
 //create fd and init
 //recvfrom allocate buffer to recv
 uint8_t *recvBuf = malloc(sizeof(info));
 info *pheader = (info *)recvBuf;
 int currLen = recvfrom( fd, recvBuf,
              sizeof(info),0,(struct sockaddr *)&peerV4,
                 &sockaddrLen);
  //error handling
  if(currLen == sizeof(info))
  {

       //close socket if end is specified in case of connection less protocol
       // strcpy to localRecv
       char *localRecv = malloc(MAX_LENGTH);
       strcpy (localRecv,pheader->clientReq);
       //do something with the values on the server like
       if (strcasecmp(localRecv,"plus")     == 0) //pseudo
            plus(ntohl(pheader->arg),ntohl(pheader->value));
  }
```